# How to make <div>s in HTML5 draggable for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, html, draggable

I am playing around with the HTML5 features, and I want div's (and similar containers like articles, sections, etc.) to be draggable. Consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>A Simple Draggable Object</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Test #1: A Simple Draggable Object</h1>
    <div draggable="true">This text should be draggable.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested in OS X the following browsers: 
In Chrome 7.0 and Safari 5.0.2 I can successfully drag the text around, but in Firefox 3.6 and 4.0b6 I can neither drag the text nor mark it (as if it was usual text). Is this a bug or a feature?
How do I achieve that Firefox lets me drag around these tags *without* using jQuery ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

According to [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/), this won't work in Firefox without some JS help.

> The HTML 5 spec says it should be as
>   simple as adding the following
>   attributes to the markup of the
>   elements in question:
>
> ```
> draggable="true"
> ```
>
> However, this doesn’t work completely
>   for Safari or Firefox. For Safari you
>   need to add the following style to the
>   element:
>
> ```
> [draggable=true] {
>   -khtml-user-drag: element;
> }
> ```
>
> This will start working in Safari, and
>   as you drag it will set a default,
>   empty value with the dataTransfer
>   object. However, Firefox won’t allow
>   you to drag the element unless you
>   manually set some data to go with it.
>   To solve this, we need a dragstart
>   event handler, and we’ll give it some
>   data to be dragged around with:
>
> ```
> var dragItems = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable=true]');
>
> for (var i = 0; i < dragItems.length; i++) {
>   addEvent(dragItems[i], 'dragstart', function (event) {
>     // store the ID of the element, and collect it on the drop later on
>
>     event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id);
>   });
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. I also found this site that helped me out:
http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: Great Q and A!  I'm having trouble doing that datatransfer with jquery.  Any Ideas?

Comment: To anyone wondering about the above question when using jQuery it appears to be: event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id)

Comment: When I tried to add setData or without it, Firefox tries to navigate to another site, based upon the id in setData.