# Make div draggable in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried the code [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977596/how-to-make-divs-in-html5-draggable-for-firefox) but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using Firefox 15, it works in Chrome.

This is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>A Simple Draggable Object</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.onload=function() {
            var dragItems = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable=true]');

            for (var i = 0; i < dragItems.length; i++) {
                addEvent(dragItems[i], 'dragstart', function (event) {
                    // store the ID of the element, and collect it on the drop later on
                    event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id);
                 });
            }

        };
</script>

    <h1>Test #1: A Simple Draggable Object</h1>
    <div draggable="true">This text should be draggable.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I bet there's a JavaScript error behind the inactivity. If you install, say, Firebug and watch its JavaScript console as you attempt to move it, do you see an error?

Comment: I've just tried it with FireBug - you have the following error: ReferenceError: addEvent is not defined

Comment: Thank's for your help, there's indeed an error there : "ReferenceError: addEvent is not defined" - but why did it work for the people on the other thread?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what drag and drop functionality you're looking for, but may be worth looking at a full tutorial e.g. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload=function() {
        var dragItems = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable=true]');

        for (var i = 0; i < dragItems.length; i++) {
          dragItems[i].addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
            event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id);
          });
        }

};
```

Worked for me. Thanks to [Kris C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42234/kris-c)