# Dragging inlined divs with hidden overflow results in wrong ghost image

Tags: html, css, draggable

I'm trying to use draggable divs, but the ghost image I get while dragging is wrong. The divs are inlined, and there is a hidden overflowing part. Here is a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. HTML:

```
<div class="box" draggable="true">
  <div class="inner-box"> </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.inner-box {
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gokjkqxm/

If you try to drag the first div, the ghost image contains a part of the second one, which is something I'd like to avoid. Does anybody know of a way to solve this issue without using images?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on how browsers handle draggable divs, I have no problem with the ghost image on Edge where Chrome seems to make the edges fade out (which is why you are seeing a part of the 2nd div). Making bigger divs (~150px) seems to solve the problem in Chrome.
Oh and also it wont work in firefox : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977596/how-to-make-divs-in-html5-draggable-for-firefox

Comment: Wow, It's shocking that it's $current_year and drag and drop is still not handled properly across browsers. Thank you for your response! I think I'll manage to get a workaround.

Comment: The divs are not draggable in many browsers.  It's easy enough to make or include your own version of dragging.  jQuery draggable for example: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: @balidani,  4 years later and I'm having the same issue.  Did you ever fix it?  Is there some css I could apply to prevent this?

Comment: I honestly don't remember what project this was for, I think I might have done what Ed suggested above but with vanilla JavaScript.